# How do I make a list that checks characters in a string and returns the count of each and 0 for the rest of the letters?

Tags: f#

I need to write a function which counts the occurrences of each letter of the alphabet in a string.

Until now I have been able to take a string and then return a list with the count of occurrences of the characters which are in the string. (So for an example if I print histogram("Absbs") the function will return [1;2;2]). But the function needs to return 0 if a character doesn't appear in the string. 
How can I do this?

```
let histogram (src:string) =
    let dat = src.ToLower() |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList
```

Also I can't use loops or mutable variables.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the quickest way, but it will work:

```
let histogram (src:string) =
    let dat = src.ToLower() |> Seq.countBy id 
    [ 'a' .. 'z' ]
        |> List.map (fun x -> match dat |> Seq.tryFind (fun (c,_) -> x = c) with
                                    | Some (p,q) -> (p,q)
                                    | _ -> (x,0) )

let bars = histogram "test this"

for c,i in bars do
    printfn "%c : %i" c i
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the `groupJoin` query syntax, which correlates the elements of two [`IQueryable<_>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1)s based on equality of keys, and groups the results. The length of the groups is the number of matches.

```
let histogram (alphabet : seq<_>) (source : seq<_>) = query{
    for letter in alphabet do
    groupJoin element in source on (letter = element) into group
    select (Seq.length group) }
// val histogram : alphabet:seq<'a> -> source:seq<'a> -> seq<int>

histogram {'a'..'z'} "test this" |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list =
//   [0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 2; 3; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;
//    0]
```

To better illustrate what is going on, this can also be written with the `GroupJoin` method from `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

```
let histogramLinq alphabet source =
    System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupJoin(
        alphabet, 
        source, 
        (fun letter -> letter), 
        (fun element -> element), 
        fun _ group -> Seq.length group )
// val histogramLinq :
//   alphabet:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a> ->
//     source:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a> ->
//       System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let histogram (src:string) =
    let lower = src.ToLowerInvariant()
    ['a'..'z']
    |> List.map (fun a -> lower |> Seq.sumBy (fun c -> if c = a then 1 else 0) )
```